# Create json array with hashtable in java

Tags: java, gson, json

I'm a little confused on how to construct associative arrays from a hashtable in java with either JSONObject() or the gson library from google.

Any help on this is appreciated!

```
    JSONObject message = new JSONObject();
    Map<String,String> responseData = new Hashtable<String, String>();
```

[...]

```
    ResultSet results = getApprovalCount.executeQuery();

    while (results.next()) {
        responseData.put("vote" + results.getString("submission_id"), results.getString("counter"));
    }
```

[...]

```
    message.put("submissions", responseData);
```

Result:

```
{"submissions":{"vote1":"2","vote7":"1","vote25":"1","vote6":"1","vote13":"1","vote9":"1","vote11":"1"}}
```

Desired result:

```
{"submissions":[{"vote1":"2"},{"vote7":"1"},{"vote25":"1"},{"vote6":"1"},{"vote13":"1"},{"vote9":"1"},{"vote11":"1"}]}
```

Comment: Oh, ok, i've seen the update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out...!

```
  JSONObject message = new JSONObject();
  ArrayList<Map<String,String>> responseData = new ArrayList<Map<String,String>>();
  User user = new User(request);
```

[...]

```
    while (results.next()) {
        Map<String,String> tmpdata = new Hashtable<String, String>();
        tmpdata.put("vote" + results.getString("submission_id"), results.getString("counter"));
        responseData.add(tmpdata);
    }
```

[...]

```
    message.put("submissions", responseData);
```

Comment: Correct, that's a list of objects with one field, didn't read too closely your update.